# How to use jsPDF library?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I want to save my webpage as PDF.
I've tried using this solution:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#printPDF').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample.pdf');
});
```

But I'm getting blank pdf.
**Is there any correction or solution to save the webpage as a PDF?**

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? What's inside `body` variable, are your defining it somewhere in your code?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors. And body is the html part. And I've not defined it anywhere.

Comment: After clicking on printPDF button, I'm getting this error in console.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.   jspdf.min.js:58

Answer (score 0):

Actually I run your code and it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.static.runoob.com/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="savepdf">
            savepdf
        </button>
        test
    </div>
    <script>
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        $('#savepdf').click(function(){
            doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
                'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since you mentioned the Uncaught TypeError, the 'name' variable was not declared. Maybe you can change a source of jspdf.min.js? Or maybe there are some conflicts between the libraries loaded.